# Is there a way to show Visual Code (tsserver) suggestions like TS80007 with tsc command (or other)?

Tags: typescript, eslint, tsc, tsserver

Visual Code (tsserver) emits some suggestions like `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression ts(80007)`

[image]

But I don't find a way to get this error with `tsc` nor `eslint` to use it on CI environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found a `typescript-eslint` rule https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/await-thenable.md

So adding this to the .eslintrc is enough:

`"@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "error"`

Comment: Thanks for that! Btw. you should mark this as answer here 